# Is there a way to monitor what cause program shut down in linux for python script?

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to figure why sometimes my python script randomly receives `SIGINT` from the linux host.

What is the usually way to debug this problem

I am currently using

```
nohup python my_script.py > /dev/null 2>&1&
```

and have since switch to

```
nohup python my_script.py > myprogram.out 2> myprogram.err&
```

Is there other log and channel I can inspect why the linux host is sending termination command to the script?

I am using aws ec2 instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
import datetime
try:
    [your_code]
except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
    # catch SIGINT
    print("{}: {}".format(datetime.datetime.now(), e), flush=True)
except:
    # catch unknown exception
    print("{}: other exception!".format(datetime.datetime.now()), flush=True)
```

Comment: Hmm, how does this tell me who is causing the termination signal?

Comment: You can debug by the help of log info

Comment: But I already know that `SIGINT` is causing the script to shut down though, I just don't know why is `SIGINT` send to the script

Comment: `SIGINT` may sent by OOM Killer, crontab program or others. You can print the process list running in linux to the log after catching `SIGINT`.

Comment: So how do I print the process list?

Comment: You can use subprocess like this: `print(subprocess.Popen(['ps', '-ef'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.readlines())`

Comment: Hmm, the dump is very hard parse though, is there a way to look at each process's history to see which process invoke SIGINT?

Comment: No way to do that. What you should do is to log as much as you can, then debug